# Problema con campos únicos en documentos embebidos de Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

agradecido de antemano.

Tengo las siguientes colecciones:

```
// Esquema de estudiante
const EstudianteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  codigoRude: {
    type: String,
    unique true,
    required: true
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Estudiante
});

// Esquema de profesor
const ProfesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rda: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Profesor
});

// Esquema de padre
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   // Otros campos propios del Padre de familia
});

// Esquema de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  estudiante: {
    type: EstudianteSchema
  },
  profesor: {
    type: ProfesorSchema
  },
  parent: {
    type: ParentSchema
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Los campos ***estudiante, profesor y parent,*** son documentos embebidos.

Al momento de insertar o guardar los documentos, resulta que sólo guarda un documento de cada tipo: ***Estudiante, Profesor, Parent.***

Por ejemplo al guardar un segundo documento de tipo ***Estudiante*** muestra el Error:

E11000 duplicate key error collection: qmuneddb.usuarios index: profesor.rda_1 dup key: { profesor.rda: null }

El problema muestra que, cuando se guarda un segundo documento de tipo ***Estudiante***, ya existe un documento con el campo rda: null en el subdocumento embebido de tipo ***Profesor*** que nada tiene que ver con los campos del Estudiante.

Entonces se podría pensar que, por la estructura que tiene el esquema ***usuario***, Mongoose, NO solamente guarda una instancia de un tipo, es decir cuando insertamos un usuario de tipo Estudiante, también inserta los otros subdocumentos embebidos ***Profesor*** y ***Parent***, aunque no se lo indiquemos específicamente.

Lo ideal sería que cuando guardes un ***usuario*** de tipo ***estudiante***, no guarde nada referido al ***Profesor*** o ***Parent***.

¿Cuál sería la solución apropiada para esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes dejar un solo campo para ambos tipos de codigo, y con una bandera especificar si es maestro o estudiante, por ejemplo , si es maestro pones 0, si es estudiante pones 1. El required solo se aplica a un campo, y es mas facil tambien la busqudeda por codigo. Si necesitas validar, puedes leer el tipo de usuario y ejecutar la validacion en funcion de ese dato.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Efectivamente el problema está en la creación del índice tipo [`unique`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) en los campos de los documentos anidados.

Se desea crear una restricción de unicidad en un subdocumento (documento anidado) de una colección de MongoDB. Sin embargo, dado que el subdocumento es opcional dentro del documento, la creación del índice falla ya que la restricción sobre el campo establece que no puede haber 2 documentos repetidos. Siendo el subdocumento opcional, al no ser embebido en la creación, los valores de sus campos tomarán un valor `null`, lo cual causa el error al querer insertar otro documento con un subdocumento opcional, cuyos campos también tomarán un valor `null`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tienes varias opciones para solucionar el problema, te presento 2 alternativas. La primera implica no usar índice de unicidad, sino que realiza una validación contra algún campo del documento principal, como puede ser el correo electrónico y el campo que deseamos único. La segunda alternativa propone la creación de un índice parcial en los campos opcionales.

**Usar el método [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) de Mongoose**

Si deseamos mantener la atomicidad de las operaciones sobre los documentos, debemos usar métodos que nos garanticen tal atomicidad.

El método `findOneAndUpdate` de Mongoose realiza una operación atómica.

Lo que haremos es eliminar la restricción causante del problema en el esquema de datos, y para asegurar la unicidad de los mismos usaremos el método `findOneAndUpdate` para guardar la información. Evitaremos la actualización de datos y sólo permitiremos la creación de un nuevo documento si los campos únicos se cumplen.

Para crear el nuevo documento usamos la opción [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/index.html) establecida a `true` y el operador de actualización [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert), que insertará un nuevo documento si no existe ninguno que coincida con el filtro de búsqueda.

Para garantizar que el documento que estamos buscando sea único, debemos establecer un valor como único en nuestro modelo, usualmente se usa el correo electrónico como campo único.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Esquema de estudiante
const EstudianteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  codigoRude: { // quitamos la restricción 'unique'
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Estudiante
});

// Esquema de profesor
const ProfesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rda: { // quitamos la restricción 'unique'
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Profesor
});

// Esquema de padre
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   // Otros campos propios del Padre de familia
});

// Esquema de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ... datos adicionales
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true // <- establecemos la restricción 'unique'
  },
  // ... otros campos
  // campos con documentos embebidos
  estudiante: {
    type: EstudianteSchema
  },
  profesor: {
    type: ProfesorSchema
  },
  parent: {
    type: ParentSchema
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

Ahora que ya tenemos nuestro modelo de datos, vamos a establecer el filtro de búsqueda.

Si un usuario desea registrarse proporcionará los datos requeridos, siendo 2 de ellos únicos: `email` y `codigoRude` (en caso de profesor) o `rda` (en caso de estudiante).

El filtro entonces debe buscar un documento que contenga uno de los 2 campos. Si la consulta devuelve un resultado, significa que ya existe un documento con alguna de esas características, por lo tanto determinamos cuál es el campo duplicado y devolvemos el mensaje apropiado. Por ejemplo:

```js
// creación de un documento basados en el modelo anterior, por ejemplo con un middleware de ExpressJS

const addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  // creamos el nuevo usuario a partir de la solicitud
  let newUser = new User(req.body);

  // establecemos el filtro
  let filter = {};

  if(newUser.profesor || newUser.estudiante) {
    let subDoc = newUser.profesor ? 
      { 'profesor.codigoRude': newUser.profesor.codigoRude } : 
      { 'estudiante.rda': newUser.estudiante.rda };
    // usamos el operador $or
    filter = {
      $or: [
        { email: newUser.email },
        subDoc
      ]
    };
  } else {
    // documentos que no son tipo profesor o tipo estudiante
    filter = { email: newUser.email }
  }

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    filter,  // <- filtro de búsqueda
    { $setOnInsert: newUser }, // <- documento a insertar si la búsqueda no devuelve resultado
    { upsert: true, new: true },  // creará un nuevo documento si la búsqueda no devuelve resultado, devuelve el documento creado / encontrado
    callback
  );
  // ...
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos la forma de crear nuevos documentos, usando una consulta atómica y que nos permitirá evitar datos duplicados en campos que deseamos que sean únicos.

Para determinar cuál campo está duplicado y enviar el mensaje apropiado al cliente podemos hacer lo siguiente dentro de la función `callback` que pasamos al método:

```js
// función callback
(error, saved) => {
  // caso de error
  if(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error occured',
      error: error.message
    });
  }
  // caso en que no se devuelvan resultados (improbable)
  if(!saved) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: true,
      message: 'Hubo un error al salvar el documento, inténtelo más tarde'
    });
  }
  
  // caso en que se creó satisfactoriamente un nuevo documento
  // (la búsqueda usando el filtro no encontró coincidencias)
  // los valores '_id' no se pueden comparar directamente, se deben convertir a string
  if(newUser._id.toString() === saved._id.toString()) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Usuario creado',
      result: saved
    });
  }

  // si estamos aquí es porque no se creó un nuevo usuario ya que la búsqueda
  // encontró coincidencias. Debemos determinar dónde se produjo el dato duplicado
  let message;
  
  // primero verificamos el correo
  if(newUser.email === saved.email) {
    message = 'El correo ya está registrado en el sistema, verifique e intente nuevamente';
  } else if(newUser.profesor && newUser.profesor.codigoRude === saved.profesor.codigoRude) {
    message = `El 'codigoRude': ${newUser.profesor.codigoRude} ya está registrado en el sistema, verifique e intente nuevamente`;
  } else if(newUser.estudiante && newUser.estudiante.rda === saved.estudiante.rda) {
    message = `El 'rda': ${newUser.estudiante.rda} ya está registrado en el sistema, verifique e intente nuevamente`;
  } else {
    // caso genérico (improbable)
    message = 'No se pudo crear el documento, intente nuevamente.'
  }
  return res.status(200).json({
    error: true,
    message
  });
}
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de insertar un documento que respete la unicidad de los datos.

*¿Porqué no usar `find` y luego `save`?*

Porque eso rompe la atomicidad del proceso, puede suceder que entre el proceso `find` y `save`, otro usuario o administrador genere un documento usando el mismo correo, o el mismo `codigoRude` o `rda`, por lo tanto nada me garantiza que cuando vaya a salvar el documento no exista otro con algún campo igual.

**Nota**

Para usar `findOneAndUpdate()` debemos establecer la opción `useFindAndModify: false` en las opciones globales de Mongoose, esto para evitar que se usen métodos obsoletos del driver de NodeJS para MongoDB, más información en la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify). Por ejemplo:

```js
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dats_base';
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoIndex: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  ssl: false, // check for using this option in production
  connectTimeoutMS: 15000,
  poolSize: 15,
  useFindAndModify: false // <- aquí
}

mongoose.connect(uri, options, callback);
```

**Usando un índice parcial sobre los campos opcionales**

Podemos crear un índice de tipo *parcial* ([*partial*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)) sobre los campos opcionales.

Para hacerlo en Mongoose, usaremos el nivel de esquema para crear el índice, y no como lo hicimos anteriormente (a nivel de campo o propiedad).

Por ejemplo:

```js
// Esquema de estudiante
const EstudianteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  codigoRude: { // quitamos la restricción 'unique' y la condición de 'index'
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Estudiante
});

// Esquema de profesor
const ProfesorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rda: { // quitamos la restricción 'unique' y la condición de 'index'
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  // Otros campos propios del Profesor
});

// Esquema de padre
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   // Otros campos propios del Padre de familia
});

// Esquema de Usuario
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ... datos adicionales
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true, // <- índice a nivel de campo, este lo mantenemos
    unique: true
  },
  // ... otros campos
  // campos con documentos embebidos
  estudiante: {
    type: EstudianteSchema
  },
  profesor: {
    type: ProfesorSchema
  },
  parent: {
    type: ParentSchema
  }
}, {collection: 'users', timestamps: {createdAt: 'created', updatedAt: 'updated'}});

// creamos índices parciales sobre los campos opcionales

// sobre 'profesor.codigoRude'
UsuarioSchema.index(
  { 'profesor.codigoRude': 1 },
  { 
    partialFilterExpression: { 'profesor.codigoRude': { $exists: true } },
    unique: 1
  }
);

// sobre 'estudiante.rda'
UsuarioSchema.index(
  { 'estudiante.rda': 1 },
  { 
    partialFilterExpression: { 'estudiante.rda': { $exists: true } },
    unique: 1
  }
);

// ahora podemos crear nuestro modelo
const Usuario = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema);
```

De esta forma los índices creados de tipo `unique` serán usados sólo si al momento de crear el documento, el campo opcional existe en el mismo.

Podemos usar entonces el método `save()` de nuestro modelo como lo hacemos usualmente y si el campo ya existe, nos devolverá el mensaje apropiado.

Por ejemplo, en un middleware de ExpressJS:

```js
const addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  let user = new Usuario(req.body); // el cuerpo de la solicitud tiene los datos del nuevo usuario
  user.save()  // usamos el método `save()` que devuelve un objeto 'thenable'
  .then(saved => {
    console.log('User saved!');
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'User saved',
      user: saved
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error occured',
      error: error.message
    });
  });
}
```

Si tratamos de crear un usuario con campo `email` repetido nos devuelve el mensaje de error:

> `"E11000 duplicate key error collection: database_name.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: \"usuario@email.com\"`

Si tratamos de crear un usuario profesor con campo `codigoRude` repetido nos devuelve el mensaje de error:

> `E11000 duplicate key error collection: database_name.users index: profesor.codigoRude_1 dup key: { profesor.codigoRude: "some_code" }`

Si tratamos de crear un usuario estudiante con campo `rda` repetido nos devuelve el mensaje de error:

> `E11000 duplicate key error collection: database_name.users index: estudiante.rda_1 dup key: { estudiante.rda: "some_rda") }`

Y lo más importante, cuando alguno de los campos es `null` ya no te dará error de campo duplicado, por lo cual podrás trabajar sin problemas.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mauricio, yo lo había solucionado de la siguiente forma: codigoRude: {
  type: String,
  unique true,
  required: true,
  sparse: true
   },
Esto permite campos nulos duplicados, solo controla como campo único cuando se inserta datos. No se si esta correcto esta solución.

Comment: Los índices tipo [*Sparse*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) se usaron hasta MongoDB 3.0 ya que no existía otro tipo. Sin embargo, a partir de Mongo 3.2, se prefiere el uso de [índices parciales](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial), ya que son menos costosos en recursos. Si usas MongoDB 3.2 o superior, mi sugerencia es que utilices índices parciales en vez de *sparse*. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio.